# How do i put a JProgressBar into a JOptionPane in java?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jprogressbar

Can anyone tell me how i can make a progress bar go from 1 to 100 percent in a JOptionPane. Its not meant to show anything in particular or have any significance, its just for fun and to simulate something happening in the game to the user.
Thanks!

Comment: Start with the [`JOptionPane` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) - remember, the `Object` message property can be a component, people seem to forget this. Also, so is not a replacement for research and effort. Try some things, if you're having trouble with a particular aspect, then give us a shout

Comment: You're probably also going to want to have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example presented below, I hope that what you looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MessageDialog");
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
    pane.setMessage("long message...");
    JProgressBar jProgressBar = new JProgressBar(1, 100);
    jProgressBar.setValue(15);
    pane.add(jProgressBar,1);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(frame, "Information message");
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
```